# Make a Matrix class that can be initialized without declaring matrix size first

Tags: matrix, initialization, smalltalk, squeak

I am new to Smalltalk and am taking a class init currently. One of the problems we were assigned requires creating a new Class "HeavyMatrix", which is called like this —

```
aMatrix := HeavyMatrix new.
```

Notice that there is no initial size assignment. The size is supposed to be undetermined upon creation. Then, the class adds values to the matrix with the following method —

```
aMatrix setRow:1 column:2 value:7.
```

All the values in the matrix which have not been declared in this way default to 0. The new Class HeavyMatrix is not supposed to subclass anything other than Object (i.e. not Matrix or Array). Can any Smalltalkers help me out? There are some other methods the class must contain but I think I can figure everything else once I am able to initialize the class. Thanks!

Comment: Just what *does* determine the size?  Will there be a point in time when the size is fixed and then the message `setRow:column:value:` becomes illegal?

Comment: Instances of your class could have an instance var of class Matrix, initially set to nil. Then when your instance receives a message of setRow:column:value: it calculates the size of a Matrix that it needs, instantiates it, and then sets the value. Subsequent calls to setRow:column:value: may require you to create a new Matrix, copy over the values of the old Matrix, and then store the new value. Not very efficient code, but it should satisfy the requirement.

Comment: No, there should never be a time when setRow:column:value: becomes illegal. I thought of creating the matrix in the setRow method call and then copying the values into a new matrix. if that method was called and declared "illegal". Indeed not very efficient... I was thinking perhaps using an extensible collection such as OrderedCollection? Whatever I use, it seems very inconvenient if that tthing has a necessary fixed size to declare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What can I suggest you… First of all you can just used ordered collections and inside `setRow:column:value:` if current column size is smaller that required than add what is missing an OrderedCollection instances. The same with desired row size (add 0s). The implementation will be something like this:

```
initialize
    rows := OrderedCollection new

setRow: aRow column: aColumn value: aValue
    | row |
    rows size < aRow ifTrue: [
        (aRow - rows size) timesRepeat: [rows add: OrderedCollection new]].
    row := rows at: aRow.
    row size < aColumn ifTrue: [
        (aColumn - row size) timesRepeat: [row add: 0]].
    row at: aColumn put: aValue

getRow: aRow column: aColumn
    aRow <= rows size ifTrue: [
        |row|
        row := rows at: aRow.
        aColumn <= rows size ifTrue: [^ row at: aColumn]].
    ^ 0
```

But more efficient way to do that is to implement a sparse matrix I think. You have a lot of structures described at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). Please note, that this matrices are only efficient when you have a low amount of elements compering to the size of the matrix itself. But if you'll check even the easiest implementation, like storing a coords-value data in dictionary, than it will suite you a lot:

```
initialize
    dict := Dictionary new

setRow: aRow column: aColumn value: aValue
    dict at: aRow@aColumn put: aValue

getRow: aRow column: aColumn
    dict at: aRow@aColumn ifAbsent: [0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So if I am understanding you correctly, you are suggesting using a point like i@j as the key in a dictionary to return the value stored at that point in the matrix?

The first method you described would involve making and OrderedCollection of OrderedCollections? Can you show how I might initialize these implementations without subclassing my HeavyMatrix class? The initialization is what I am having the most trouble with as a beginner in smalltalk. Thanks again.

Comment: @WesField I've added some code for my first suggestion. Still don't understand your problem with subclassing

Comment: So I would like to get the values of a row in an array using a do: statement using i@j. For example I wanted to say something along the lines of 
    rows do: [ :i@j | .....etc...].
For some reason it doesn't like i@j. Suggestions?

Comment: @WesField this is another question. Read about how blocks work. If you need to pass to arguments into a block the syntax is next: `[:i :j | …statements…]` or you can pas just a whole point instance and access a and y in a block body

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. The last part of it asks to implement a second class, LazyMatrix, in which the previous instance variable, "rows", is replaced by "block". This new instance variable must implement a block instead of a Collection. The new LazyMatrix must be basically the same as HeavyMatrix (extensible, default values 0). Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. You can't use a block to store data in it. Maybe the idea is that you pass a block upon creation to define a matrix by formula? For example `LazyMatrix new: [:i :j | i + j]`. This way each value will be calculated on demand. But will be predefined

Comment: Ok, so I think I figured out how to do this. It involves a s-expression matrix. So the initial value of block:= [nil]. When we call setRow:column:value: it sets the block to [#(i j value).[nil]], each call to setRow adds [#(i j value)... and this defines a new block. This is similar to a lazy list. So now the question becomes how to access the head of this block. I know that calling value will evaluate the tail i.e. [#(i j value).[nil]] of a block [(#i j value).[#(i j value).[nil]]]. Is there a simple way to call the head and the tail of this block? Thanks!

Comment: @WesField is there any reason why a block in this situation is better than an array for example?

Comment: No, of course not. It is just the requirement assigned my our crazy professor.